Determine total trend given unit trend and proportion
I have data (below table) on trend (% over 10 years) in units of a whole. I also know the proportion of the whole each unit makes up. I want to do three things.

Calculate overall trend given that information
Calculate what the trend needs to be in each unit, given current proportions, if I want the overall trend to change to 2% over the next 10 yrs
Calculate what the trend needs to be in Unit 12 to reach a goal of 2% over the next 10 yrs if if all other unit trends (and proportions) stay the same

I keep searching for 'trend analysis' to find the answer but that doesn't provide what I need. Any direction would be appreciated.



Unit
Proportion of total
10yrT




1
0.073
0.29


2
0.009
1.13


3
0.003
0.29


4
0.003
-0.46


5
0.315
-1.77


6
0.013
-0.26


7
0.007
1.54


8
0.003
4.57


9
0.227
-2.35


10
0.202
-1.45


11
0.008
-0.13


12
0.139
-0.79



